# Connecting to SQL Server database from another computer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm new to SQL Server, and have been following this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345343%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

I carefully followed all the steps, but when I try to connect to the database from the other computer, I get the error

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be
>   used with `Windows authentication`. Microsoft SQL Server, Error:
>   18452

What steps do I need to take to fix this?

Thanks

(I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 on both the machines)

Comment: Probably this helps: http://secretgeek.net/boring_sql_one.asp

Comment: Try by using Sql Server Authentication. log in with an account authorized to connect to SQL Server.

Comment: Beter connect using Sql Server Authentication enter uid,pwd.
If u still wnt to connect window authentication then enable guest permission so through lan u can access

Comment: @satindersingh Which UID/pwd am i supposed to enter?

Comment: @satindersingh How do I enable guest permission?

Comment: @yomayne: Need info tell me in ur SqlServer 2008 r2 u logged in by window authentication or server authentication ?? Also both the pc are connected by lan/internet ?

Comment: @satindersingh I'm logged in by windows authentication, and the PCs are connected via Wireless LAN

Comment: Thanks @Rain I was able to do it finally with SQL Authentication. Still figuring out how to do it by Windows Authentication though.

Comment: Thanks @satindersingh I was able to do it finally with SQL Authentication. Still figuring out how to do it by Windows Authentication though.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

The user attempted to login with credentials that cannot be validated. Possible causes are:

The login may be a SQL Server login but the server only accepts Windows Authentication.

You are trying to connect using SQL Server Authentication but the login used does not exist on SQL Server.

The login may use Windows Authentication but the login is an unrecognized Windows principal. An unrecognized Windows principal means that the login cannot be verified by Windows. This could be because the Windows login is from an untrusted domain.

For more detail [please see this article](http://www.microsoft.com/products/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=18452).

Answer (score 0):

Right click your **database** >> **Properties** >> Select **Files** (on left top). >> click **owner** (right top) popup window display >> click  **browser** check **Guest, NT Authority\System**

Open sql expand click **Security** >> right click **Login** >> **New Login** >> Click **search** (right top ) >> **Advanced** >> **Find Now** >> Select **Guest/Network**
This will add guest login

may this help you out

Comment: @yomayne: what options u are getting let me know ?

Comment: [BUILTIN\Users]
[NT AUTHORITY\System]
[NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER]
[sa]
[<my name>]